# How to justify sound propagation is a linear time-invariant (LTI) system?

Tags: waves, acoustics, signal-processing, linear-systems

**Background**

A linear time-invariant (LTI) system (black box) is one described by the system:
\begin{align} 
        \dot{\xi}(t) & = A\xi(t) + B\omega(t), \; \xi(0) = 0 \label{eq-abc-1}\\
\lambda(t) & = C\xi(t)
\end{align}
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ($n$ is the dimention of the system) and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ ($m$ is the dimention of unputs of the BB model), and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ ($p$ is the dimention of outputs). $\xi$ describes the states of the system and $\lambda$ is the output function.

Out of this system of ODE (called state space representation), the concepts of **impulse response**, **impulse**, **convolution**, transfer function etc, arises.

In acoustics, the concept of impulse response (IR) is often used for reverberation of a room: one generates a loud short duration sound in a room in order to acquire the room IR, then one can convolve the IR with any sound signal and simulate the response of the room quite successfully.

In this particular case, we are thinking of the system whose inputs are the emission of a sound wave from a fixed point $P_0$, and the outputs are the resulting sound in a fixed point $P_1$ in the same room.

**My question**

*In physics (acoustics) how does one justify that there is a ``state space'' representation of this system?, how do you justify that you can apply all the theory of LTI systems to sound propagation?*

I'm asking this, because that's what is assumed when one measures the IR of a room and many other acoustical scenarios.

I've seen justifications like the *ray tracing* approach, where you are just adding the same input signal a lot of times lagged due to the reflections of the room, and you magically have a convolution, but my concern is if *there is a justification involving  differential equations in acoustics that have a state space representation*.

If there is a need for clarification in my question just let me know.

Comment: You have to make some (quite valid) assumptions to characterise a room as an LTI system. First and foremost is the fact that the system is passive. This is a valid assumption to make for a room without any sources in it. Then you should definitely assume the room to have time-invariant characteristics, at least for durations longer than your measurements. This is valid for simple cases and rather short durations (where for example the temperature does **not** change). These make the system passive (which is not linear but is a good step towards it) and time-invariant. To assume a (cont.)

Comment: (cont.’ed) linear system you have to accept that the governing equations are linear. Since the **linearised** wave equation, which is used to model the system **is** linear (:D) then the whole system is considered to be linear.

Comment: @ZaellixA I agree with what you say, but the (linearised) wave equation is a partial second order differential equation, how do I see the wave equation as a linear ODE?

Comment: I believe you could convert the PDE to a system of ODEs through the separation of variables method. You can look this up (or have a look [here](https://www.public.asu.edu/~hhuang38/pde_slides_sepvar-heat.pdf), this may help). I am not an expert in state-space representation of systems (this is more of control than acoustics and audio which are “my fields”) but I believe there is an approach where you can add an extra equation and convert PDEs to systems of ODEs (I believe you’ll need either as many as the free variables, or one more).

Comment: @ZaellixA thanks! I'll look into it. And yes!, state space is more control theory than acoustics, but (as far as I know) the concepts of impulse response, convolution etc, come from control theory (and linear time invariant ODE), but at the same time, these concepts are used in acoustics/audio/signal processing very often, and that's what I'm trying to understand, how these two branches are related to eachother.

Comment: Yeah, I believe I cannot help too much here, as I always relied on the “simple” justifications I provided above (they seem more like intuition sometimes) to convince myself that a room can be modelled as an LTI.

Answer (score 1):

Sound waves are not linear, but since we rarely have shock waves indoors, we can usually approximate the sound wave equation as linear for room acoustics.

While simple boundary conditions will, in some cases, allow us to solve these problems using symbolic analysis, generally we resort to numerical finite element methods for problems like this. We approximate a linear PDE as a set of linear ODEs on a grid. There's your state.

Of course now you should see that if we make the grid infinitely fine, we recover the PDE. The grid of state variables becomes a continuous state function. The LTI theory still works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can I check the details of ''we approximate a linear PDE as a set of linear ODEs on a grid''?  ZaellixA comment linked a pdf where they show the PDE can be seen as two ODEs, but they are not linear.

Comment: @CésarVB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method